# Error in building marmalade demo

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio-2008, marmalade

I am an android app developer, recently I am trying to learn Marmalade to develop games. First I've done with installation on one laptop which was running on Win 7 and was working fine, but when I am trying to run it on another laptop which was running on Win XP, the following error is showing up, even when I am running one of their hello world demo:

> 1>------ Build started: Project: s3eHelloWorld_vc9, Configuration:
>   X86 Debug Win32 ------ 1>Compiling... 1>cl : Command line warning
>   D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/S3Eproject' 1>s3eHelloWorld.cpp
>   1>c:\marmalade\5.2\examples\helloworld\build_s3ehelloworld_vc9\temp_defines_debug.h(78)
>   : fatal error C1189: #error :  "Wrong compiler used.  Please run
>   s3eConfig to configure Visual Studio" 1>Creating browse information
>   file... 1>Microsoft Browse Information Maintenance Utility Version
>   9.00.30729 1>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. 1>BSCMAKE: error BK1506 : cannot open file
>   '.\Debug_s3eHelloWorld_vc9_x86\s3eHelloWorld.sbr': No such file or
>   directory 1>Build log was saved at
>   "file://c:\Marmalade\5.2\examples\HelloWorld\build_s3ehelloworld_vc9\Debug_s3eHelloWorld_vc9_x86\BuildLog.htm"
>   1>s3eHelloWorld_vc9 - 2 error(s), 1 warning(s)
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

I've been using eclipse since I started developing, so I don't know anything about Visual Studio. Am I missing something here? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this same issue on the [Marmalade forums](http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/devnet/forum/5104).

It appears one fix it to install VS2010. Otherwise, the forum has multiple other things to try.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh.. Just need to set the path `C:\Marmalade\5.2\s3e` at System variable and all worked. ;)